# Is there programming language which can tolerate runtime errors?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a programming language which can consume the following input:

```
m = 1;
n = 2/0;
print(n);
print(m);
```

and successfully print "1" on the screen?

Maturity of that language and quality of implementation doesn't matter much.

EDIT: Don't take question explanation literally. I'm not interested in division by 0. I try to find a language which is insensitive to (almost) all runtime errors.

Comment: You should note that `2/0` is a valid expression in many languages. Perhaps add something which more explicitly causes an error :)

Comment: Can't many languages handle that with a `try{...}catch{...}` block?

Comment: By the way, the way you structured your question, it should be `print`, not `prints`. :-) (`Is there a programming language which can consume the following input and successfully print "1" on the screen?`)

Comment: Well, if there was such a language, it wouldn't actually _be_ a runtime error, would it? It reminds me of the "what happens when an irresistible force meets an immovable object?" question. It cannot happen. The existence of an irresistible force precludes the existence of an immovable object, and vice versa.

Comment: Actually, on review, I feel slightly bad about closing this. It's incredibly obvious to most programmers that there is such a language - any language with runtime error handling; which is almost every language, but it's still a question. You should review the typical error-handling systems languages have, try/catch being the most popular.

Comment: I'm not sure people understand what the questioner is asking. It's not about if try/catch exception handling exists. It's about whether there is a language that will, without any other constructs, raise an error/exception. For instance, maybe the language assigns default values to all variables. Also, maybe when some procedure does something that would, in most languages cause a runtime error, it would act as if nothing happen (such as passing messages to `nil` in Objective-C). I don't think there is anything wrong with this question.

Comment: Voted to reopen. In practice the arithmetic operations that lead to "undefined" or "infinite" results may or may not lead to runtime errors. My answer points out one of them.

Comment: If you require that the program can produce errors that are quietly dismissed without the programmer explicitly handling them, then it seems to be that what you want is a programming language in which *statements may or may not execute and you will not know whether they did or not*.  That seems... unuseful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Basic: `On Error Resume Next`

And I'd like to point out that most languages can handle the above with whatever keywords the languages allow for hooking into interrupts.

Comment: +1 for cheekiness with VB, but avoids breaking code flow with try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

[ EDIT ]

Okay, after OP's edit, it seems I completely misunderstood the question. Nevertheless I am still leaving my answer here as someone might get some new information from it and anyway deleting it would serve little purpose.

---

Take a lazy language like Haskell. Define `print` so that it `tries` to print the value ignoring any error that occurs while printing. And there you have it, a language that behaves as described in your question.

Code example in Scala:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import util.control.Exception._
import util.control.Exception._

scala> def print[A](x: => A) {
     |   ignoring(classOf[Exception]) {
     |     println(x)
     |   }
     | }
print: [A](x: => A)Unit

scala> lazy val m = 1
m: Int = <lazy>

scala> lazy val n = 2 / 0
n: Int = <lazy>

scala> print(n)

scala> print(m)
1
```

(Note: Scala is not a lazy language by default, but supports lazy semantics optionally)

Answer (score 1):

### In Mathematica you don't need an error catching command

Pgm:

```
Off[General::infy] (*Turn off infinity error messages*)  
m = 1;  
n = 2/0;    
Print[n];     
Print[m];
```

Output:

```
ComplexInfinity
1
```

If you omit the first line (the error suppressing command), and additional *warning*  message is printed:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
```

Moreover, you can operate with the "ComplexInfinity" value of n:

```
 Print[1/n]
```

gives

```
 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Any language that uses IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic. Divided by zero is Infinity.

For example in Javascript:

```
> 1/0
Infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, our COBOL teacher in school used to say that 'COBOL is the only programming language which allows division by zero' (without giving a runtime error).

Answer (score 0):

Dependently typed programming languages such as Idris, Agda or Coq will not compile if you ever try to do an illegal action. Here is a safe example of your code in Idris.

```
safeDivide : Nat -> (y:Nat) -> so (y /= 0) -> Nat
safeDivide x y p = div x y

main : IO ()
main = 
  print (show 1)   -- compiles successfully
  print (show (safeDivide 2 1 oh))   -- compiles successfully
  -- print (show (safeDivide 2 0 oh))   -- throws an error at compile time
```

Dependently typed languages allow you to write proofs so that their type system can verify that your code will work the way it should. By defining `safeDivide` with a proof (`so (y /= 0`), you're guaranteeing that your program won't even compile if `0` is ever propagated to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Bourne Shell:

```
M=1
N=expr 2 / 0
echo $N
echo $M
```